# Need to check if below command lines can be converted in .sh

Tags: linux, shell

Linux Command – VMDR Linux (.rpm)

1. Install `sudo rpm -ivh QualysCloudAgent_RHELx86.rpm`
2. Assign Customer Id and Activation ID `sudo /usr/local/qualys/cloud-agent/bin/qualys-cloud-agent.sh ActivationId=<> CustomerId=<>`

Comment: Your question is extremely opaque.

Answer (score 1):

Create file `script.sh` with this content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
rpm -ivh QualysCloudAgent_RHELx86.rpm
/usr/local/qualys/cloud-agent/bin/qualys-cloud-agent.sh ActivationId="$1" CustomerId="$2"
```

And launch:

```bash
sudo ./script.sh activationId customerId
```